# Deleted user seen as a Bot on Hangouts

Tags: google-workspace, google-hangouts

Our users from one specific room are trying to search the part of conversation with user which is not longer working in our company. The part of his conversation is seen as Bot and they can't enter to his thread. When they searched his directly on chat they have acces to conversation, and this guy is seen as "Deleted user". Where is the problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by `seen as Bot`? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I added screenshot

Comment: Bealive me it's not the bot

Comment: Can you provide a set of reproduction steps for this? It might be appropriate to report this in Issue Tracker, using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=350158&template=1047346).